# Out of Memory Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I let my app in background, switch many apps, then return my app.
My app freezes and gets out of memory errors because of navigation,.......

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 24 byte allocation with 77088 free bytes and 75KB until OOM, target footprint 268435456, growth limit 268435456; giving up on allocation because <1% of heap free after GC.
        at java.util.HashMap.newNode(HashMap.java:1746)
        at java.util.HashMap.putVal(HashMap.java:630)
        at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:611)
        at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:219)
        at java.util.Collections.addAll(Collections.java:5458)
        at com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.zzs.zzh(com.google.android.play:core@@1.10.3:13)
        at com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.zzs.zzc(com.google.android.play:core@@1.10.3:2)
        at com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.zzaa.getInstalledModules(com.google.android.play:core@@1.10.3:1)
        at com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.zzl.getInstalledModules(com.google.android.play:core@@1.10.3:1)
        at androidx.navigation.dynamicfeatures.DynamicInstallManager.needsInstall(DynamicInstallManager.kt:100)
        at androidx.navigation.dynamicfeatures.DynamicIncludeGraphNavigator.onRestoreState(DynamicIncludeGraphNavigator.kt:158)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.onGraphCreated(NavController.kt:1114)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.kt:1086)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.kt:1039)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onCreate(NavHostFragment.kt:155)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:3090)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:475)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:257)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:142)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:136)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:248)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:227)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1073)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1001)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
        at vn.com.vndirect.stocks.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:44)
        at vn.com.vndirect.stocks.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:38)
        at vn.com.vndirect.stocks.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:56)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8051)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8031)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3612)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3796)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2214)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7842)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

I have no idea or why its out of memory. Please help me, thanks

Comment: Consider editing your question with your written code instead of posting in answer's comment. It may be missed if you do the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your manifest file in `<application>`

```
<application
  android:hardwareAccelerated="false", 
  android:largeHeap="true" 
...>
```

It will work in some environments. In most instances, it is caused by using large images in your app. I recommend you resize your images to avoid `OutOfMemoryError` error due to a huge bitmap in memory.

Comment: Log Error does not show bitmap reason, the reason is navigation. I have fixed it same to you but the app still error

Comment: How are you calling your fragment? Share more details.

Comment: `<fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
   android:name="androidx.navigation.dynamicfeatures.fragment.DynamicNavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph_main" />`

Comment: i have nav_graph_main in activity

Comment: and nav_graph_main has many <include-dynamic>, example below

Comment: `<include-dynamic
        android:id="@+id/nav_graph_notification"
        app:graphPackage="${applicationId}.notification"
        app:graphResName="nav_notification"
        app:moduleName="notification" />`